# mixing audio files in node.js

Tags: node.js, audio

Is it possible to mix 2 or more audio files(first.mp3, second.mp3) into a seperate file (mixed.mp3) using node.js?
The mixed.mp3 file need be created from the starts of the selected files and not a concatenation of them. any help will be appreciated